Diff of 2 or more .coverage file (from Azure DevOps Code coverage tab)
We are building .NET Framework 4.8 in C# with MsTest v2 using OnPrem Azure DevOps Pipelines (with TFVC). When the build completes, we have a quality gate step that validates that coverage has increased.
The thing is, sometimes, for instance, we get a decrease in coverage even though no change was done to testable code. We would like to be able to easily compare the coverage report (.coverage files) from run #1 to the one from run #2 to see where we lost ground.
As of now, I start 2 instances of Visual Studio, load one coverage file in each and manually look at every line until I find the difference but, due to the size of the solution, this is extremely time consuming.
Is there any way of automating this? I tried looking at the file but it seems to be some binary format I wouldn't know how to exploit.

You can use the third-party extension ReportGenerator with PublishCodeCoverageResults@1.
- task: reportgenerator@5
  inputs:
    reports: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
    targetdir: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/coverlet
    reporttypes: Cobertura
    verbosity: Verbose

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/coverlet/Cobertura.xml

Then you can see code coverage report like:

Click the class, you can see more details.


Only looking at your screenshots, while the report may be interesting for not having to open VS to look at the coverage report, I don't see how this could help me compare coverage from Build#1 to Build#2. Am I missing something?

You can see line coverage, branch coverage and class details from the report above, which can facilitate your comparison and analysis. You can open two windows to compare. Currently, the default feature in DevOps does not support automatic comparison of coverage reports between different runs. If you want such a feature, you can submit feature request here. You can also download Cobertura.xml locally and use the Compare function of VS code or notepad++ to compare the coverage report.

Thank for the information if I ever need to do it in the web interface but if you look closely at the OP, you'll see that I was doing the exact same procedure but using Visual Studio as my coverage viewer. What I'm looking for is an automated comparison tool.

There isn't such feature supporting automatic comparison of coverage reports between different runs in Azure DevOps. You can submit a feature request to Azure DevOps. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. You can share the request here and someone who also wants this feature can follow and vote.

What is the best place for Auzre Devops Feature Requests?

You can submit a feature on Developer Community.
